# Javascript checkboxes with <asp:checkbox />

Tags: asp.net, javascript

The Javascript checkbox script ([by ryanfait](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)) worked beautifully when I used it at first. Then I needed to alter the form I made so that asp.net could process the form, but now the checkboxes are default.

Is there a way to alter the script to make it work on the asp:checkbox?
I call the function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').checkbox(); 
    });
```

And [here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/custom-form-elements.js) is the actual javascript.

I have two different types of checkboxes on my page at the moment, one `<asp:Checkbox ... />` and one `<input type="checkbox" ... />`. The second one gets styled, the asp checkbox doesn't...

I haven't contacted Ryan Fait yet, as I hoped this was a common "bug".

EDIT:
The way the script works is, it finds all elements with class="styled", hides it and then puts a span next to the element. Somehow in my sourcecode, for the asp:checkbox this happens too early I think. Look:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" /><span class="styled"><input id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolderRightColumn_newsletter" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$contentPlaceHolderRightColumn$newsletter" /></span>
```

The span is there, visible and all, which it should not (I believe, as the first checkbox shows up in the style I want it to be, the second doesn't).

*So far, I found a part of the problem. The javascript cannot change the asp checkbox somehow, but when I manually add the span the javascript is supposed to create, the checkbox doesn't work as a checkbox anymore. I added some details in my answer below.*

Comment: If you put an <asp:Checkbox and an html checkbox side by side and then do : $('input:checkbox').length  - is that equal to 2 ?

Comment: Well there you go, there's a problem in the plugin. Try to write the same structure in html as asp.net generates it. See if you see different behavior. Also install firebug and see if any errors are generated.

Comment: I will (next monday xD). Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.. the javascript in the link is not a jquery plugin. What's the .checkbox() method suppose to do ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I might have a skewed perception of the term plugin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

Forget about the RyanFait Solution, this one works on ALL checkboxes. :D

```
var boxes;
var imgCheck = 'Images/checkbox-aangevinkt.png';
var imgUncheck = 'Images/checkbox.png';

function replaceChecks(){ 

    boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if(boxes[i].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') { 
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            if(boxes[i].checked) {
                img.src = imgCheck;
            } else {
                img.src = imgUncheck;
            }
            img.id = 'checkImage'+i;
            img.onclick = new Function('checkChange('+i+')');
            boxes[i].parentNode.insertBefore(img, boxes[i]);
            boxes[i].style.display='none'; 
        }
    }
}
function checkChange(i) {
    if(boxes[i].checked) {
        boxes[i].checked = '';
        document.getElementById('checkImage'+i).src=imgUncheck;
    } else {
        boxes[i].checked = 'checked';
        document.getElementById('checkImage'+i).src=imgCheck;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an ID on your checkbox and then reference it by that ID, like so:

```
<asp:checkbox id="mycheck" />
```

Then reference it like this:

```
$('#mycheck').checkbox();
```

If that doesn't work, do what many, many web developers before you have done: download Firefox, install Firebug, and check your selector logic in the console. I find it's always easier to develop in Firefox, even when my target platform is IE.

Comment: that has very small chances o working as asp.net will probably generate the id like ctl00_..._mycheck .

Comment: sirrocco is right. Also, I have an id defined for the processing of the form already and when i use that in the script, still no style :(

Comment: Gah. I hate technologies that munge the ID. JSF does the same thing. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I found part of the answer.

When I add the span the plugin creates manually like so:

```
<span class="checkbox" style="background-position: 0pt 0pt;"><asp:CheckBox ... /></span>
```

I do get the nicely looking checkbox UNDERNEATH the actual checkbox!
However, the styled box is not interactive. It doesn't change when I click it or hover over it nor does it register the click. It's basically not a checkbox anymore, just a goodlooking square. The actual asp checkbox that shows up *does* register clicks, but it's the ugly standard one.

```
<span class="checkbox" style="background-position: 0pt 0pt;"><asp:CheckBox ID="anId" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden;" /></span>
```

The visibility: hidden makes the "real" checkbox dissappear and leaves the goodlooking yet broken one.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem could be caused by the fact that asp:CheckBox controls are automatically wrapped in a span tag by default, and setting the CssClass attribute on the asp:CheckBox control actually adds the class to the span (not the input) tag.

You can set the class on the input tag using the 'InputAttributes' as follows:

```
chkMyCheckbox.InputAttributes.Add("class","styled");
...
<asp:checkbox id="chkMyCheckbox" />
```

This should then allow you to target the checkbox with your existing JavaScript.

Comment: That, sir, is the cause of many problems. I am growing to avoid ASP controls unless it is absolutely necessary to do otherwise. I just ended up using an <input type="checkbox" runat="server" />

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the 'type' attribute. Does the following work for you?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').....etc
});
```

Comment: No, this gives the same result.
When I add a "regular" html checkbox, that one does get the new style, yet the asp:checkbox doesn't.

Comment: That's really odd. If you compare the rendered source (view source in your borwser, is there any difference in rendered markup)

Comment: There is, actually... The asp:Checkbox is wrapped in a span with class styled, due to the javascript. The html checkbox isn't... you're onto something. Thanks!